# validate custom input component with vee validate

Tags: validation, vue.js, vee-validate

i have custom input component called **nationality-selector** and i use it like this:

```
      <validation-provider
        v-slot="{ errors }"
        rules="required"
        class="w-100"
        name="Nationality"
      >
        <nationality-selector v-model="form.nationality" :errors="errors[0]" />
      </validation-provider>
```

this is **vee-validate.js** plugin:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { ValidationProvider, extend } from 'vee-validate'
import * as rules from 'vee-validate/dist/rules'
import { messages } from 'vee-validate/dist/locale/en.json'

Object.keys(rules).forEach((rule) => {
  extend(rule, {
    // eslint-disable-next-line import/namespace
    ...rules[rule],
    message: messages[rule]
  })
})

Vue.component('validation-provider', ValidationProvider)
```

problem is that vee validate couldn't validate **nationality-selector**.
but on other custom component it works fine.

Comment: Could you please clarify which input type you are unsing in the nationality-selector component?

Comment: nationality-selector needs to emit input events for it to work with validation provider.